# How to merge two dataframes of unequal size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe with 26 columns, 'A' through 'Z' and 100 rows, and a second dataframe with 3 columns,'C' through 'E' and 30 rows. The first dataframe is missing 50 entries each in columns 'D' and 'E', so what I need to do is overwrite columns 'D' and 'E' in the first dataframe wherever 'C' in the first dataframe == 'C' in the second dataframe.

Currently because it is easy I store the second dataframe in a list of tuples and I update the first dataframe in batches using for loops and many locs. It takes hours, though, because its a large dataframe for my computer and in each loop im finding where the large dataframe's column 'C' == the first entry in the tuple, and then updating that entry one at a time.

The code below works, but is ridiculously slow. I am thinking what I should do is store the tuples in a dataframe instead and that perform some kind of merge, but I keep getting the error 'ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)'

```
for trio in slow_TUP:
    g = pair[0]
    w = pair[1]
    z = pair[2]
    df['D'].loc[df['C'] == g] = w
    df['E'].loc[df['C'] == g] = z
```

Answer (score 1):

For readalibility of examples I limited the number of columns
in the first DataFrame (*df*) to 5.

Assume that it contains:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1
1  a2  b2  c2  d2  e2
2  a3  b3  c3  d3  e3
3  a4  b4  c4  d4  e4
4  a5  b5  c5  d5  e5
```

The other DataFrame with data to update (*dfUpd*) contains:

```
    C    D    E
0  c2  DD2  EE2
1  c4  DD4  EE4
```

so rows with *C* = *c2* or *c4* should be updated.

To do it, start with setting the index in *df* to *C* and saving it
in a temporary DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.set_index('C')
```

The result is:

```
     A   B   D   E
C                 
c1  a1  b1  d1  e1
c2  a2  b2  d2  e2
c3  a3  b3  d3  e3
c4  a4  b4  d4  e4
c5  a5  b5  d5  e5
```

Then to perform the actual update (for now in-place, still in *df2*), run:

```
df2.update(dfUpd.set_index('C'))
```

When you print *df2* again, the result is:

```
     A   B    D    E
C                   
c1  a1  b1   d1   e1
c2  a2  b2  DD2  EE2
c3  a3  b3   d3   e3
c4  a4  b4  DD4  EE4
c5  a5  b5   d5   e5
```

For the time being *C* is still the index.

So to complete the task, you should:

- reset the index (but after it *C* column is at the **first** place),
- reindex columns with columns from *df* (to bring back the original
  column order),
- save the result back in *df*.

All these operations can be performed in a single instruction:

```
df = df2.reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

The result (the content of *df*) is now:

```
    A   B   C    D    E
0  a1  b1  c1   d1   e1
1  a2  b2  c2  DD2  EE2
2  a3  b3  c3   d3   e3
3  a4  b4  c4  DD4  EE4
4  a5  b5  c5   d5   e5
```

Comment: You've saved me a lot of time. With the first method I was using it took sometimes hours to update hundreds of thousands of rows, but with your method that bottleneck is completely gone and Im done in minutes. Cant thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

Given df, df2 as two dataframes: you could easily do:

```
df = df.set_index('C')
df2 = df2.set_index('C')
```

And then:

```
df.loc[df2.index, df2.columns] = df2
```

This will overwrite all of df where `df.C == df2.C` with df2 values, in the columns that df2 does have, without affecting other columns.

Example:

```
df
Out[31]: 
    a      b      c  d
0  12  213.0  231.0  2
1  31    NaN    NaN  1
2  24    NaN    NaN  5
3  53    NaN    NaN  4
4  44  132.0  231.0  2
5  32  455.0  211.0  1

d2
Out[32]: 
    a    b    c
0  24  214  221
1  53  244  111

result #after using the above method
Out[33]: 
        b      c  d
a                  
12  213.0  231.0  2
31    NaN    NaN  1
24  214.0  221.0  5
53  244.0  111.0  4
44  132.0  231.0  2
32  455.0  211.0  1
```